# How do I echo an <ul> tag once in a while loop in PHP?

Tags: php, html

Thanks for taking a look at my question, what I'm trying to do is output an *ul* once but have it's *li* elements loop normally within the while loop, if the UL is echoed more than once it messes up my website styling.

My solution was to create two variables which would contain the opening and closing UL tags and then establish if statementz to put the variables values to an empty string once the while loop iterated once... well that didn't work:

```
    $ulStart='<ul class="grid cs-style-6">';
    $ulEnd='</ul>';
    $checkIteration=0;
    $checkIteration2=0;

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {

            if($checkIteration>0){
                $ulStart='';
                $checkIteration++;
            }

            if($checkIteration2>0){
                $ulEnd='';
                $checkIteration2++;
            }

         $fd= $fd.$ulStart.'<li>
              <figure>
               <img src="fakedir/someimageregular-'.$somestuff.'.png">
               <figcaption>
               <h3>'.$fake.'</h3>
               <span>'.$fake_var.'</span>
               <a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">Take a look</a>
              </figcaption>
             </figure>
            </li>'.$ulEnd;


        }
```

Any ideas on how I could achieve this? I would **greatly** appreciate any help on this! THANK YOU!

Comment: hey you can just write ul tag outside the loop why are you trying to write inside loop.

Comment: If you want to use it once only, why are you writing it in a loop ?

Comment: @bodil132 try the solution   which i have given may helps you.

Comment: @Ms.Nehal the ul tag needs to be in the same echo declaration statement otherwise I get this: 

<ul class="grid cs-style-6"></ul>

<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>

Comment: `</ul>` use this after while loop i.e. after the loop end, just like as it is mentioned in @Dinesh Bhojvani answer. And start `<ul>` before while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fd = "";
$fd .='<ul class="grid cs-style-6">';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $fd .='<li>
          <figure>
           <img src="fakedir/someimageregular-'.$somestuff.'.png">
           <figcaption>
           <h3>'.$fake.'</h3>
           <span>'.$fake_var.'</span>
           <a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">Take a look</a>
          </figcaption>
         </figure>
        </li>'



}
$fd .='</ul>';
echo $fd;
```

`echo`ing the `echo '<ul class="grid cs-style-6">';` will already generate the closing tag for `<ul>` i.e. `</ul>`. Best options to these things are, save the whole html in a variable and then echo the html once the loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try below code may it helps you.

```
   $fd = "";
    echo '<ul class="grid cs-style-6">';
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $fd .='<li>
              <figure>
               <img src="fakedir/someimageregular-'.$somestuff.'.png">
               <figcaption>
               <h3>'.$fake.'</h3>
               <span>'.$fake_var.'</span>
               <a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">Take a look</a>
              </figcaption>
             </figure>
            </li>'



    }
   echo $fd;
    echo '</ul>';
```

i think you have no need to write ul inside loop here what i have did write ul outside the loop.before loop open ul tag after loop close. And if you need `ul` tag ones then no need to write in loop.  i hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: the ul tag needs to be in the same echo declaration statement otherwise I get this: <ul class="grid cs-style-6"></ul> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li>

Comment: any error occur or what happen can please tell me output

Comment: it echoes the <li> outside the <ul> :

<ul class="grid cs-style-6"></ul> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li>

Comment: Even this wont work. echoing the <ul> will also generate the close tag for `<ul>`. And thus adding the `<li>`'a outside the `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like `<ul>` to be in the same echo statement you can do:

```
$fd = "";   
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $fd .='<li>
      <figure>
       <img src="fakedir/someimageregular-'.$somestuff.'.png">
       <figcaption>
       <h3>'.$fake.'</h3>
       <span>'.$fake_var.'</span>
       <a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">Take a look</a>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </li>'

}
echo '<ul class="grid cs-style-6">' . $fd . '</ul>';
```

But it's almost the same as Dinesh Bhojvani answer so I am not sure it will help.